How to solve this question about the beta distribution in a Bayesian analysis?
This question appeared in Prof. Babak Shahbaba's book (Biostatistics With R: An Introduction to Statistics Through Biological Data) in the questions of its chapter 13.

Q4. Suppose that we are interested in the proportion of population
affected by diabetes among Pima Indian women. Let us represent the
diabetes status of each person by random variable X, where X = 1 if
the person has diabetes and X = 0 if the person does not. Then we can
assume that X has a Bernoulli distribution with parameter μ. We know
that the population proportion of diabetic women in the whole US is
about 10%. We want to use this information to specify our prior for μ.
Use R-Commander to find a beta distribution that has relatively high
probability density values around 0.1. For this, plot different beta
distributions by changing the parameters until you find a distribution
for which the area under the probability density curve is large over
the interval from 0.05 to 0.15. Then, use the Pima.tr data (available
from the MASS package) to find the posterior probability distribution
of μ. Use the posterior probability distribution to obtain the point
estimate and 95% credible interval for μ.

My trial
library(tidyverse)
library(MASS)

x <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)
dfb1 <- tibble(x, prob = dbeta(x, shape1 = 1, shape2 = 9), curve = "Beta(1, 9)", line = 1, sh1 = 1, sh2 = 9)
dfb2 <- tibble(x, prob = dbeta(x, shape1 = 0.5, shape2 = 5), curve = "Beta(0.5, 5)", line = 1, sh1 = 0.5, sh2 = 5)
dfb3 <- tibble(x, prob = dbeta(x, shape1 = 10, shape2 = 90), curve = "Beta(10, 90)", line = 1, sh1 = 10, sh2 = 90)
dfb4 <- tibble(x, prob = dbeta(x, shape1 = 0.1, shape2 = 0.9), curve = "Beta(0.1, 0.9)", line = 1, sh1 = 0.1, sh2 = 0.9)
dfb5 <- tibble(x, prob = dbeta(x, shape1 = 100, shape2 = 900), curve = "Beta(100, 900)", line = 1, sh1 = 100, sh2 = 900)

df <- dfb1 %>%
  dplyr::bind_rows(dfb2) %>%
  dplyr::bind_rows(dfb3) %>%
  dplyr::bind_rows(dfb4) %>%
  dplyr::bind_rows(dfb5) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(curve = factor(curve)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(line = factor(line)) %>%
  group_by(curve) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(xhigh = sh1 / (sh1 + sh2), highest = dbeta(x = xhigh, shape1 = sh1, shape2 = sh2)) %>%
  ungroup()

ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x, prob, color = curve, linetype = line), size = 0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(xhigh, highest, color = curve), size = 3) + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2", name = "Curve") +
  scale_linetype(guide = "none") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), breaks = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)) + 
  theme_minimal()

Plot

My trial answer
pbeta(q = 0.15, shape1 = 0.1, shape2 = 0.9, lower.tail = TRUE) - pbeta(q = 0.05, shape1 = 0.1, shape2 = 0.9, lower.tail = TRUE) #0.08547915
pbeta(q = 0.15, shape1 = 0.5, shape2 = 5, lower.tail = TRUE) - pbeta(q = 0.05, shape1 = 0.5, shape2 = 5, lower.tail = TRUE) #0.2712344
pbeta(q = 0.15, shape1 = 1, shape2 = 9, lower.tail = TRUE) - pbeta(q = 0.05, shape1 = 1, shape2 = 9, lower.tail = TRUE) #0.3986325
pbeta(q = 0.15, shape1 = 10, shape2 = 90, lower.tail = TRUE) - pbeta(q = 0.05, shape1 = 10, shape2 = 90, lower.tail = TRUE) #0.9139534
pbeta(q = 0.15, shape1 = 100, shape2 = 900, lower.tail = TRUE) - pbeta(q = 0.05, shape1 = 100, shape2 = 900, lower.tail = TRUE) #0.9999987
pbeta(q = 0.15, shape1 = 1000, shape2 = 9000, lower.tail = TRUE) - pbeta(q = 0.05, shape1 = 1000, shape2 = 9000, lower.tail = TRUE) #1

So, I guess the parameters shape1 and shape2 should be 100 and 900, respectively, since they have a large probability density area  (p = 0.9999987) around 0.1. Is my conclusion right?
What is required?
I am interested in solving this part:

For this, plot different beta distributions by changing the parameters
until you find a distribution for which the area under the probability
density curve is large over the interval from 0.05 to 0.15.


Are you asking us to confirm that your plots are correct?

Yes, and most importantly, how to try different parameters other than the ones plotted?

Change the numbers in your code.

Pls read "what is required" part of the question.

"How to try different parameters" was directly answered by "change the numbers"

Let's re-write some of your code to make this a little easier to solve.  First, note that the beta distribution can be re-parameterized in terms of $\mu$, its mean, and $\kappa$, a parameter which controls how narrow the distribution is.  You can think of $\kappa$ as an "effective sample size" when using the beta distribution as a prior.  If I set $\kappa = 10$, then its like I observed 10 data points which I then used to generate the prior.
The parameters $\alpha, \beta$ can then be re-written as
$$ \alpha = \mu \times \kappa $$
$$ \beta = (1-\mu) \times \kappa $$
You can verify, for example, that $\mu = \alpha / (\alpha + \beta)$ and $\kappa = \alpha + \beta$.
Let's plot some of the distributions under this parameterization.  We really only need to vary $\kappa$ since we know $\mu = 0.1$, so this effectively turns your problem into a 1 parameter problem that you can vary quite easily, hence easily trying other parameterizations than the ones you've plotted.
library(tidyverse)

param_grid <- tibble(mu = 0.1, 
                     kappa = c( 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 25000)) 



layers <- map2(param_grid$mu, param_grid$kappa, ~{
  
        param = glue::glue("k = {.y}")
         stat_function(
           aes(color = param),
           fun = dbeta, 
           args = list(shape1 = .x*.y, shape2 = (1-.x)*.y), 
           n = 1000,,
           xlim = c(0, 0.2)
         )
       })


Reduce(`+`, layers, init = ggplot())



So as $\kappa \to \infty$, the density is going to get larger too.  Let's also plot the probability density between 0.05 and 0.15 to see how that changes as we vary $\kappa$.


param_grid <- tibble(mu = 0.1, 
                     kappa = seq(10, 100000, 10)) 

param_grid %>% 
  mutate(
    area = pbeta(0.15, mu*kappa, (1-mu)*kappa) - pbeta(0.05, mu*kappa, (1-mu)*kappa)
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(kappa, area)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_log10() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, length.out = 11))



So from this plot, anything after around $\kappa = 100$ will result in a beta distribution in which the area between 0.15 and 0.05 is greater than 0.9.  Since the question does not define "large", I will take 0.9 to mean large.  This means that the parameterization is
$$ \alpha = 100 $$
$$ \beta = 900 $$
Of course, the area can only become so large since the total area under the distribution must be 1.  As $\kappa$ gets larger, your prior is going to get stronger and stronger, which means it would require more data to allow the likelihood to inform the prior.  The solution, IMO and from what I've read, is to find an area which is "large enough", but not so close to 1 so as to prevent any data contained in the dataset to which the author is referring  from providing additional information.
As for the last part of the question, we can count how many diabetic observations we have in the data and how many observations we have total.
diabetic <- sum(MASS::Pima.tr$type == 'Yes')
n <- nrow(MASS::Pima.tr)

There are 68 observations out of the 200 that are diabetic.  To find the posterior, simply compute
$$ \tilde{\alpha} = \alpha + 68 $$
$$ \tilde{\beta} = \beta + 200 - 68 $$
for whatever $\alpha, \beta$ you choose using the information above, and find credible intervals as required.  One way to do this would be to use the qbeta function as follows
qbeta(c(0.025,0.975),100 + diabetic, 900 + n - diabetic)
[1] 0.1209537 0.1601827

Using the prior I've chosen, the credible interval is approximately (0.12, 0.16).

Thanks a lot, perfect answer.
